# PHP convert array to desired string format

Tags: php, sql

I have an array of id's in the below format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 13
)
```

and have a date variable `$date = '16/07/14';`
I have to build a SQL query in the below format so that i can insert multiple rows in the single insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO  `attendances` (student_id, date) values (5,$date), (9,$date), (13,$date);
```

So how to convert the id array and date variable to string format through which i can get  `(5,$date), (9,$date), (13,$date)` .

Comment: Use `mysqli`s or `PDO`s prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to modify the array structure, iterate through the array while generating the SQL should do the trick:

```
$array = array(5, 9, 3);
$date  = '16/07/14';

$comma = '';
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `attendances` (student_id, date) VALUES';

foreach ($array as $val) {
    $sql .= $comma . '(' . $val . ', "' . $date . '")';
    $comma = ', ';
}

echo $sql;
```

If you must modify the array structure, try `array_walk()`:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key) use ($date) {
    $item = array($item, $date);
});

print_r($array);
```

The above code will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 16/07/14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 16/07/14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 16/07/14
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat it into variable first then run your SQL query, like below:

```
$delimiter = ''
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `attendances` (student_id, date) VALUES';
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $sql .=  $delimiter . "(". $value .",". $date .")";
    $delimiter = ',';
}
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I misunderstood your question, just edited my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<?php
$a = array(5, 9, 3);
$date = '16/07/14';
foreach($a as $k){
    $result .= "(".$k.",'".$date."'),";
}
echo rtrim($result, ",");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
$sql='INSERT INTO  `attendances` (student_id, date) values ';
$count = count($array);

if($count > 0){
    $i=1;
    foreach ($array as $a){
        if($count ==$i){
            $sql.=" ($a,$date) ";
        }else{
            $sql.=" ($a,$date), ";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can execute the sql query multiple times using foreach loop. So your code will be

```
foreach($array as $value)
INSERT INTO  `attendances` (student_id, date) values ($value,$date);
```

Comment: That's not a very nice solution if the user uses a query string where you can put multple values into the DB with one execution. If it would be a prepared statement, executing it multiple times would be pretty fine.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, your point is absolutely correct and one more thing here is performance. Because, `INSERT` is in loop now that means it will hit many times to DB ti insert.